# How does linker finds standard and WinAPI functions?

Tags: c++, c, windows, linker

When I want to use something from standard C/C++ library I can just include appropriate header and use that function. The same thing with WinAPI functions.

I understand how compiler finds these headers - it searches them localy then if not found looks up in some predefined system folders.

But I cant figure out how does linker findes those libraries because I dont include them in any way...

Answer (score 4):

If you use Visual Studio 2012 with default settings, in addition to C Runtime, linker will link against the following:

kernel32.lib
user32.lib
gdi32.lib
winspool.lib
comdlg32.lib
advapi32.lib
shell32.lib
ole32.lib
oleaut32.lib
uuid.lib
odbc32.lib
odbccp32.lib

You can see the list yourself if you right click on project, properties -- linker -- input -- additional dependencies.

You can drop some or add some if you want to.

As for the C Runtime, it is controlled by /NODEFAULTLIB linker option, more details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tz4da4a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: A header might also include a lib via `#pragma comment(lib, "NAME")`.

Answer (score 1):

The linker simply has a standard library coming with the compiler itself.
For example, if you install GNU GCC, then you'll see a folder `lib` which contains all of the static libraries the linker uses to link your code.

If you need to tell the linker to use a specific library or some static libraries from somewhere else, you can always use the `-l` or `-L` flags (for GNU GCC) to indicate that you want the linker to use a specific library or folder of libraries.

Comment: I understand that those libraries lie in some folder in fact, but how does linker find appropriate lib or dll for the functions I use in my code? Does it just search by name in every dll export table??

Comment: @SkySurfer It will build up some sort of internal lookup table with the names of everything in all the linked libraries. How this is done internally in the linker will probably vary quite a lot from product to product. The GCC linker should be open source, so you can go ahead and look how it is done there. (Personally I couldn't care less about how it is done, as long as it works)

Comment: For a general overview of how a linker works with libraries, a quick google search revealed this: http://www.lurklurk.org/linkers/linkers.html#linker2